# Docker Postgres Container keeps respawning on macOS

Tags: postgresql, docker

I created a trivial `Dockerfile` to build an image based on the [official Docker PostgreSQL](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres) image:

```
FROM postgres
```

As far as I can tell, I did not even start it explicitly, I only `docker build .` it.

Now, whenever I try to remove the container, it keeps getting recreated and restarted:

```
hostname:~ username$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
postgres            <none>              e84edf994e8b        3 weeks ago         234MB

hostname:~ username$ date && docker ps -a
Thu May 24 13:26:31 CEST 2018
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
6482553729a4        postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes        5432/tcp            some-postgres.1.a0udiazm08y67gcxhnxbhinh8

hostname:~ username$ date && docker stop 6482553729a4 && docker rm 6482553729a4
Thu May 24 13:26:47 CEST 2018
6482553729a4
6482553729a4

hostname:~ username$ date && docker ps -a
Thu May 24 13:26:52 CEST 2018
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7d180c7a4532        postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 seconds ago       Created                                 some-postgres.1.jlqe02b1zt9o77gh8ky4zhzr9

hostname:~ username$ date && docker ps -a
Thu May 24 13:27:01 CEST 2018
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7d180c7a4532        postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 seconds ago      Up 7 seconds        5432/tcp            some-postgres.1.jlqe02b1zt9o77gh8ky4zhzr9
```

I tried drastic measures, too:

```
hostname:~ username$ docker kill $(docker ps -q) && docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q) && docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
7d180c7a4532
7d180c7a4532
Untagged: postgres@sha256:1c2cc88d0573332ff1584f72f0cf066b1db764166786d85f5541b3fc1e362aee
Deleted: sha256:e84edf994e8bc77bf6c60970a2bd32c905ed8782296e67aa46c949a4b47cb678

hostname:~ username$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
70f3de1d4b8a        e84edf994e8b        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   45 seconds ago      Up 40 seconds       5432/tcp            some-postgres.1.alq5qjn7adyjvbjeo023kx2fq
```

Apparently, that container doesn't even need a local image to run:

```
hostname:~ username$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
```

I tried rebooting, restarting the Docker daemon, I searched the container image's [`Dockerfile`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-library/postgres/master/10/Dockerfile) and [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker-library/postgres/master/10/docker-entrypoint.sh) for some `keep-this-container-running-at-all-costs-even-if-it-pisses-off-the-user` option, but there doesn't seem anything that strikes me as related.

I did notice there is a `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/com.docker.supervisor -watchdog fd:0` process running which possibly keeps restarting containers, but that thought is pure speculation and also, I can't seem to find anything that tells Docker to keep restarting that container and not any of the others.

I'm not a Docker expert, but I have used a number of public / official containers and also created some of my own and I have never seen this problem before.

What is going on here ?

Comment: Did you try going to `navigation bar -> docker -> preferences -> Reset -> Reset to factory deafaults`? it sounds like a one-time problem, on my mac I've experienced restarting containers before but it never persisted after forcibly purging docker - I use Edge version.

Comment: Yes, that seems to have fixed the issue. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Good to hear it helped. Posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hard-way for resetting Docker in such (usually) one-time situations. I've had a few situations like this before but it never persisted after forcibly purging docker.

You should go to:

`navigation bar -> docker -> preferences -> Reset`

And do: `Reset to factory deafaults`

Answer (score 0):

Another less drastic way:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) &
   docker update --restart=no $(docker ps -a -q)
```